# Having trouble writing the number of neighbors method for Conway's Game of Life in Java. Formatting in a 2D array, 10 by 10 matrix

Tags: java, arrays, file, input, 2d

I am working on a class assignment for Conway's Game of Life in Java. The requirement is to write the matrix in Java using a 10 by 10 2D matrix.

I have written the following code below. The `NumberOfNeighbors(int[][] board, int row, int col)` method does not work, I am not sure why. I have solved the problem using a boolean 2D array matrix and am working on a solution for an int[][] matrix. I got confused when writing the DeadOrAlive method which references the `NumberOfNeighbors()` method.

I cannot see why the `NumberOfNeighbors(int[][] board, int row, int col)` method is failing.

```
package com.cis2151.proj1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class Life 
{

private static final int ROWS = 10;
private static final int COLS = 10;
private static Scanner inputFile;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int[][] board;
    board = new int[ROWS][COLS];
    ReadFile(board);
    PrintArray(board);
    System.out.println();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        board = NextGeneration(board);
        PrintArray(board);
        System.out.println();
    }

} // end main

public static void ReadFile(int[][] board) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("numbers");
    inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    String line;

    for(int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++)
        {
            line = inputFile.nextLine();
            for(int c = 0; c < COLS; c++)
            {
                String temp = String.valueOf(line.charAt(c));
                board[r][c] = Integer.parseInt(temp);
            } // end c
        } // end r
} // end ReadFile()

public static void PrintArray(int[][] board)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}


public static int[][] NextGeneration(int[][] board)
{
    int[][] newBoard = new int[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS ; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS ; j++)
        {
            newBoard[i][j] = DeadOrAlive(board, i, j);
        }
    }
    return newBoard;
}



public static int DeadOrAlive(int[][] board, int r, int c)
{
    int neighbors = NumberOfNeighbors(board, r, c);
    int deadOrAlive = 0;


    if (board[r][c] == 1 && (neighbors == 2 || neighbors == 3))
        deadOrAlive = 1;
    else if (board[r][c] == 0 && neighbors == 3)
        deadOrAlive = 1;
    else
        deadOrAlive = 0;

    return deadOrAlive;
}


private static int NumberOfNeighbors(int[][] board, int row, int col) 
{
    int neighbors = 0;
    for(int i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++)
        {
            if ( !(row == i && col == j))
            {
                if ( insideMatrix(board, i, j))
                {
                    neighbors++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return neighbors;
}

private static boolean insideMatrix(int[][] board, int row, int col) 
{
    return row >= 0 && row < ROWS && col >= 0 &&
            col < COLS;
}
}
```

Console Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Correct solution-

```
package com.cis2151.project1;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Life
{
private static Scanner inputfile;

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    boolean[][] cells = ReadFile();
    PrintBoard(cells);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cells = nextGeneration(cells);
        PrintBoard(cells);
    }

}


public static boolean[][] ReadFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[10][10];
    File file = new File("Numbers.txt");
    inputfile = new Scanner(file);
    for(int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
    {

        for(int j = 0; j < matrix[0].length; j++)
        {
            if (inputfile.hasNextInt() && inputfile.nextInt() != 0)    
            {
                matrix[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}


public static void PrintBoard(boolean[][] matrix)
{
    String cell = "";
    for(boolean[] i : matrix){
        for(boolean val : i)
            if(val)
                cell += "1 ";
            else
                cell += "0 ";
        cell += "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(cell);
}

public static boolean[][] nextGeneration(boolean[][] cells)
{
    boolean[][] nextGenerationOfCells = new boolean[cells.length][cells[0].length];
    int newCellGenerated;
    for (int i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cells[0].length; j++)
        {
            newCellGenerated = NumberOfNeighbors(cells, i, j);
            if (rulesOfLife(newCellGenerated, cells[i][j]))
            {
                nextGenerationOfCells[i][j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return nextGenerationOfCells;
}

public static boolean rulesOfLife(int numberOfNeighbors, boolean alive){
    if( alive && (numberOfNeighbors == 2 || numberOfNeighbors == 3))
        return true;
    else if (!alive && numberOfNeighbors == 3)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


private static int NumberOfNeighbors(boolean[][] cells, int r, int c) {

    int deadOrAlive = cells[r][c] ? -1 : 0;
    for(int i = r - 1; i <= r + 1; i++)
    {
        for(int j = c - 1; j <= c + 1; j++)
        {
            if( insideMatrix(cells, i, j) && cells[i][j] )
            {
                deadOrAlive++;
            }
        }
    }

    return deadOrAlive;
}


private static boolean insideMatrix(boolean[][] grid, int i, int j) 
{
    return i >= 0 && i < grid.length && j >= 0 &&
            j < grid[0].length;
}

}
```

Console Output:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this to the condition line :

```
            if ( insideMatrix(board, i, j))
            {
                neighbors++;
            }
```

becomes :

```
        // we also need to make sure the neighbour is alive
        if ( insideMatrix(board, i, j) && DeadOrAlive(board,i,j)==1)
        {
            neighbors++;
        }
```

EDIT :

Also you should implement an overflowing algorithm (simulating a spherical world), so that elements on line 0 will check neighbors on line n instead of line -1

Comment: Thank You, testing code.